An english, japanese/gangster themed movie that looked like a stage set?
I'm looking for a movie that I once saw. These are all the details I can remember:

I'm pretty sure that the movie was released post 2000. 
The movie was in english
I think the director was famous for this style?
It may have been somewhat of an homage to japanese culture
It begins with a man riding a train into town. 
The town looks like one of those stages with stage props, except done better. 
The frame of the scene would have looked like as if you were watching a broadway show. 
I remember there was a group of gangsters that may have been wearing red and were carrying tommy guns. A few of them (3? 4?) appeared on the roofs of one of the buildings on the stage.
There was one scene that took place indoors in a sushi restaurant. I think there was a fight scene in the restaurant.


Sounds a lot like Bunraku from 2010.

Bunraku is a 2010 martial-arts action film written and directed by Guy Moshe based on a story by Boaz Davidson. The film stars Josh Hartnett, Demi Moore, Woody Harrelson, Ron Perlman, Kevin McKidd, and Gackt and follows a young drifter in his quest for revenge.
The title Bunraku is derived from a 400-year-old form of Japanese puppet theater [...] The classic tale is re-imagined in a world that mixes skewed reality with shadow-play fantasy. Its themes draw heavily on samurai and Western films.

It starts with a nameless stranger drifting into town on a train and a sushi bar figures into the plot. You can see its theatrical sets in the trailer:




YES. This is it! Wow, that was quick.

I'm not sure if I should be sad that it's got 19% on rotten tomatoes though...

Well, it's pretty to look at, I'll give it that...
